# What should we do with this JavaScript code coverage question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question

Good day! I wanted to ask your opinions with regards to a specific question.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53249/are-there-any-good-javascript-code-coverage-tools

The question was asked in '08, most of the answers there are from '08~'09 and are severely outdated. The question is currently closed and locked due to its mostly subjective nature.

I feel like this question, as it currently stands, causes damage to visitors from Google receiving outdated information.

**So what do we do?** - We could delete it, unlock and improve it, leave it as is, or if anyone has a better idea, I'd love to hear it.

What do you think? Please post your opinions as answers below, so that they can be voted and discussed individually.

Comment: I think edition is our friend here.

Comment: It's remarkable that it's locked 4 years after the question. Of course it is not relevant if i see the answers. I don't suggest an edit because people can check the dates and may skip it since they would think that it is "outdated" even if you have edited it. I would delete that and probably open a new question. But this requires maintenance from volunteers ...

Comment: To me this deserves the same treatment as the book listing question. Its off-topic and has long ago run its course. Phantom delete it, please.

Comment: You probably want to listen to [this podcast](https://soundcloud.com/stack-exchange/stack-exchange-podcast-32) first.

Comment: @HansPassant: Transcript please ;-)

Comment: It gets into the repocalypse right away, you'll get the gist of it in the first 5 minutes.

Comment: There's a problem here that goes beyond that one question and affects tool recommendation questions generally. One of the main reasons tool recommendations are off-topic here is that they go obsolete quickly, and yet the standard, officially-blessed way of dealing with them is *closure*. That is, we've observed that a class of questions have rapidly-changing answers and decided that the right way to respond to this is keep them on the site but forbid providing new answers, guaranteeing harmfully obsolete information will be at the top of Google forever. This is a completely insane policy.

Comment: @MarkAmery That's a good point. Do you have an alternative policy in mind? Would love to hear your opinion on a separate meta post.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I'd be perfectly happy for (clear, programming-related, sufficiently well-specified) tool recommendation questions to be made on-topic; I *don't* think that becoming rapidly obsolete actually stops questions from working well in the SE model, *as long as* people are free to provide new answers. But failing that, a policy of much more aggressive deletion of tool recommendation questions would be preferable to the status quo. The current middle-ground is the worst of both worlds.

Comment: @MarkAmery This really isn't the right place to discuss this. We can't vote properly, or have comment on each others' opinions properly. If you feel strongly about this (and I suspect that you do), please consider opening [another meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) and detail your ideas. Worst case, it doesn't get accepted, best case, policy change! Things won't get any worse by it ;)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The question *and* its answers are extremely outdated.
The existing answers can't be improved without fundamentally changing the contents of the answers.

The only way to salvage this question would be to allow *new* answers. But the question really shouldn't be re-opened, as it doesn't meet SO's standards.

Since the question and its answers can be misleading to visitors, and there really is no way to properly salvage it, I'd say the best option would be to:

### Delete it.

Answer (score 10):

I'm very much in favor of deleting the question but ...

... in the general case, move any valuable content to a tag-wiki. For the question discussed either to the [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) or the [code-coverage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/code-coverage) tag are candidates.

That last tag wiki could use some love anyway....

However, based on the comment feedback it doesn't look like anything valuable is salvageable from that train wreck.

And don't get me wrong. I don't care what strangers on the internet think or how they googled their way in. But I do think we under estimate the features we have at our proposal today to keep (high) quality value around while it turned out not to be a good fit for the Q/A format. Just give those tag-wiki's a reason to exist and direct anyone looking for tutorials/tools/broad stuff to those wiki's.

Comment: Is there really any useful content in the answers which 0.5s of search-engineing can't provide?

Comment: I can't judge that @BillWoodger and on first glance I think you have a point. But if the reddit javascript group finds out we deleted yet another high-viewed/liked/linked/loved question I rather be prepared. We *tried* to give the info a place of their own. And we can't stress enough how useful tag-wiki's are but under used. Instead we get Documentation....

Comment: You mean some... people... from something called "reddit" get to push SO around so it needs to keep... poor... content? There's stuff I'd like to see migrated to dregs.stackoverflow.com I didn't know it would hurt the eyes of some poor bunnies at reddit.

Comment: @rene I honestly don't care what reddit thinks. I care about the quality content on the site. And indeed if there's useful content on that question, I'd very much like to preserve it.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha you don't get my point, edited my answer to make that more clear

Comment: When the top voted answers starts with *"A quick google search revealed...*" I think that says it all. It would be better if that quick google search revealed the actual thing instead of an old scrapyard here on SO.

Comment: @ivarni: You shouldn't forget that [so] is a major player in the "information found from Google" game. We *want* information to be found on [so]. But we also want that information to be of high quality and correctness.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha Exactly. Which is why I don't think it's good if people google X and then land on a SO answer saying *I just googled X and found...*. It seems pointless to me to google something just to be told what that google term would have reported 3 years ago. It's my opinion that SO is here to give me more than a random article/library.

Answer (score -14):

Unlock and improve it's a good idea, although the question will still remain a bit old.

The only problem I see here is that the "accepted answer" will remain in the first position by default (I'm open to suggestions here).

Anyway, maybe the first "filter" should be search for a similar question. If there's a similar but "updated" question, then delete is a good choice.